# Do I need to show original letter of invitation from Poland on airport after arrival to Schengen area?

Tags: poland, invitation-letters

A friend of mine will send me an invitation letter. I do not require Schengen tourist visa, but I could have an invitation letter. So, when he has the approved letter of invitation, should I show it in original in airport or it's okay if I travel with a scanned one?

Comment: What do you mean by "approved"?  Who will have approved it?  Why don't you want to carry the original?

Answer (score 1):

Invitation letters are not generally required.  If immigration officers doubt your stated purpose, they will likely want to phone your friend to confirm it.  If the officers believe you, they won't ask for evidence to support your claim.

Invitation letters are easily forged, so they don't have a great deal of evidentiary value.  A copy of an invitation letter may have slightly less value than an original, but "less than not a great deal" is still "not a great deal."

Comment: I doubt that an immigration officer would call any friend.

Comment: @Neusser I know they do in the UK.  It's easier to call to confirm a story than it is to refuse entry.  But I have no personal experience with Polish immigration officers.

Comment: This is interesting. How can the immigration officer be sure that the person on the other end is the "friend" and not my criminal henchman?

Comment: @Neusser the same way they can be sure that I'm actually planning to sleep in the hotel whose booking I just showed them instead of hiding in the basement of the houses of parliament with several kegs of gunpowder: they can't.